# How to use scrolling in ElasticSearch with Java API Client (Elastic 8.x)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to process whole collection in Elasticsearch 8, atomicity is not required, so, please do not suggest "search after".

I used scrolls before, but struggle to properly construct code for latest Java client.

```
        var search = client.search(q -> q.index("addressbook")
                .scroll(Time.of(t -> t.time("1m"))), AddressBookRecord.class);
        String scrollId = search.scrollId();

        ScrollResponse scroll = null;

        do {

            scroll = client.scroll(q -> q.scrollId(scrollId), AddressBookRecord.class);

            System.out.println(scroll.hits().total().value());
            System.out.println(scroll.hits().hits().size());

        } while (scroll.hits().total().value() > 0L);
```

`scroll.hits().hits()` is always empty, even on first call.

At the same time `scroll.hits().hits().size()` contains right number of documents.

Also, I cannot process documents, because `.hits()` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you like it or not, but scrolling over large result sets is [not recommended in Elastic 8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html), so [search-after together with point-in-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) is the way to go:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.FieldValue;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.Time;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.Query;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.QueryBuilders;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.ClosePointInTimeResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.OpenPointInTimeResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.search.Hit;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.search.HitsMetadata;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
public class PagingTest {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient;

    @Test
    public void testPointInTime() throws IOException {

        // Open a point-in-time
        final Time keepAlive = new Time.Builder().time("1m").build();
        final OpenPointInTimeResponse pitResp = elasticsearchClient.openPointInTime(req -> req.index("books").keepAlive(keepAlive));
        final String pitId = pitResp.id();

        final Query query = QueryBuilders.match().field("author").query("Shakespeare").build()._toQuery();

        // Run your paginated queries
        String lastId = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            SearchRequest.Builder searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder()
                    .pit(pit -> pit.id(pitId).keepAlive(keepAlive)) // It would be better to use the pit from the last result
                    .size(100)
                    .query(query)
                    .source(source -> source.filter(filter -> filter.includes("id", "title")))
                    .sort(sort -> sort.field(field -> field.field("id"))).timeout("10s");

            // Continue after last id       
            if (lastId != null) {
                searchRequest = searchRequest.searchAfter(FieldValue.of(lastId));
            }

            final SearchResponse<Book> searchResponse = elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest.build(), Book.class);
            final HitsMetadata<Book> hitsMetadata = searchResponse.hits();
            assertThat(hitsMetadata.hits()).isNotEmpty();

            for (Hit<Book> hit : hitsMetadata.hits()) {
                final Book book = hit.source();
                log.info("{} | {} ", i, book);

                lastId = book.getId(); // remember the last retrieved id
            }
        }

        // Close your point-in-time to save resources
        final ClosePointInTimeResponse pitCloseResp = elasticsearchClient.closePointInTime(req -> req.id(pitId));
        assertThat(pitCloseResp.succeeded()).isTrue();
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    private static class Book {

        private String id;
        private String title;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you guide me to any documentation on this ? Unfortunately, the official Elastic doc on the Java API Client seems rather poor to me...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: this code uses the deprecated API for Elastic 7.x**

You can try to use the `SearchRequest` class:

```java
    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest("addressbook");
    searchRequest.scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L));
    searchRequest.source(new SearchSourceBuilder().size(100)); // Adjust the size according to your requirements
    
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
    
    while (true) {
        SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
        scrollRequest.scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L));
    
        SearchResponse scrollResponse = client.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        SearchHits hits = scrollResponse.getHits();
    
        // Process the documents in the hits
        for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
            // Process the individual document
            String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
            // Perform your action here
        }
    
        // Clear the scroll if no more hits are returned
        if (hits.getHits().length == 0) {
            ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
            clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
            client.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            break;
        }
    
        // Update the scrollId for the next iteration
        scrollId = scrollResponse.getScrollId();
    }
```

Comment: This code is for deprecated api (Elastic 7.x )

Comment: @OlegGritsak thanks for your comment - you are right. If a look in the docs I only can find, the `searchAfter` solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest("addressbook");
searchRequest.scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L));
searchRequest.source(new SearchSourceBuilder().size(100)); // Adjust the size according to your requirements

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

while (true) {
    SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
    scrollRequest.scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L));

    SearchResponse scrollResponse = client.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    SearchHits hits = scrollResponse.getHits();

    // Process the documents in the hits
    for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
        // Process the individual document
        String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
        // Perform your action here
    }

    // Clear the scroll if no more hits are returned
    if (hits.getHits().length == 0) {
        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        client.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        break;
    }

    // Update the scrollId for the next iteration
    scrollId = scrollResponse.getScrollId();
}
```

try to use `SearchRequest` class

Comment: Looks like  ES 7.x api again