# how to judge PIT ID is still alive with Java API Client (Elastic 8.x)?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

To get the next page of results,  should  I return  lastId and pitId by  the previous search    ?

i refer to this article
[How to use scrolling in ElasticSearch with Java API Client (Elastic 8.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387505/)

```
final Time keepAlive = new Time.Builder().time("1m").build();
        final String pitId;

        if (dto.getPitId() != null && !dto.getPitId().isEmpty()) {
            pitId = dto.getPitId();
        } else {
            final OpenPointInTimeResponse pitResp = esClient.openPointInTime(req -> req.index("message").keepAlive(keepAlive));
            pitId = pitResp.id();
        }
```

what if the params pitId expired over one minute ，how to judge ?

how could i update the pitId by keepAlive to extend the pitId's retention period ?
i only find the api closePointInTime() to delete

Answer (score 0):

every search you don't need to pass PIT on `RequestBody` or `RequestParam`
but search_after need some parameters not just lastId. you can get them using this command:

```java
List<FieldValue> sorts = hit.sort();
```

Update sort from the second time

```java
List<FieldValue> sort = new ArrayList<>();
sort.add(FieldValue.of(lastId));
sort.add(FieldValue.of(lastorderId));
searchRequest = searchRequest.searchAfter(sort);
```

By the way , id use the long data type cannot correctly show in kibana
if you always get the first page, consider whether to pass the correct value.